# Cant install .NET application in Clients PC

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

My client's PC runs Windows 7 Ultimate with .netframework 4 client profile. I am unable to install my application developed in VS2008. I tried uninstalling .NET Framework 4 From his PC and running the Clean up tool provided by Microsoft. But still I am unable to install it successfully. It provides Error 1001.

I tried running the program as administrator. I also tried to Turn on .net 3.5 feature from add or remove program.

Thanks in advance. :)

Edit:

The error what i get is shown here.

[image]

Furthermore,

1. I have confirmed that it is a 32bit processor and i run x86 release version of setup
2. The application is developed in a Windows 7 OS with .NET Framework 3.5
3. I have installed this application in 7 PCs which have .NET 3.5 installed in them and having OS Windows XP,Vista and Windows 7; and all are working fine.
4. In clients PC, when I try to install .NET 3.5 again, the installer starts but then it disappears suddenly without doing anything
5. I have tried turning on .NET 3.5 framework feature from control panel> Program and Features.
6. I have tried running the program as Administrator
7. I have tried setting the application setup in Windows XP and Vista compatible mode.

But still the issue persists.

Thanks :)

Comment: it will be really helpful if you can provide more details. What do you mean when you say that you are unable to install your application. And why did you uninstall .net framework?

Comment: .NET 3.5 SP1 is pre-installed on Windows 7.  Do try to avoid doing a lot of damage to the machine.  Surely this is a problem with your program or installer, not the .NET install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it finally...nothing was stopping my application but Crystal Reports.
We forgot to include Crystal Reports Basic as a prerequisite.

Thank you guys for the efforts taken. :)

Niraj

Answer (score 2):

@Niraj.. hope you recognize me.. :)

Well, I think the issue is with your installer. Something in your package settings is conflicting with the environment at your client's computer. With the error message that you posted, it looks like there is some dependency on some assembly which isnt available to the installer, and hence its failing. This might include version number mismatches too.

You should also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581750/error-with-windows-installer-unable-to-get-installer-types), which talks about an issue similar to yours.

or try using [FusLogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.90).aspx) to check which assemblies fail to load at runtime.

Comment: Hi Danishbhai, ofcourse i remember you. Thanks for you inputs, I will try the solutions suggested by you.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have only .net framework 4 client profile which is a subset of the .NET Framework 4 and is optimized for client applications. Please make sure that everything needed for your new application is included in client profile version. Also it is possible that your application installer requires .NET Frw 3.5 as a dependency. Anyway as already said by Henk no need to do anything with .NET Frw 4 just install 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

There is an exception raised during the installation, and you should as it wished to collect MSI debug log and other necessary information to troubleshoot.

I don't think .NET 4 is the root cause. Otherwise, you should already install this app after uninstallation of .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion

1. be sure that you not run X64 application in X86 based computer
2. trying to run them in compatibility mode for OS depend on which OS you used in client system
3. check the prerequested component are installed or not in client system.
4. you show the problem 1001 in snapshot so you can Read the log for more information about the setup you trying to install on client side.

your setup forced client system to load a specific type during the installation and type not exactly load as setup want so they give you a exception called "LoaderException"

for more information start googling may be it solved your problem

http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=loaderexception+in+.net&qscrl=1