# C# windows service installs on debug not on release

Tags: c#, windows-services, release

I have a custom built windows service that uses a custom library that my team has built.  It runs and installs fine in debug mode, but when I install it on release mode, I get the error 
"Unable to get installer types in WindowsService.exe assembly"

Any thoughts?  I am installing it via installutil in cmd prompt

Comment: What have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581750/error-with-windows-installer-unable-to-get-installer-types

Comment: I don't have a set up project so the solution doesn't really help me

Comment: Try to decompile your release-mode assembly (http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) to check if it really has the installer class. Maybe you're using an old version of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO the way I solved this, which might be a cop out, was to compile both the dll it uses and the windows service in release mode with platform of any CPU.  Was trying to keep both in x64, was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I did change Release platform target to x86 which is same as Debug platform target and installer worked properly.