# installation Exception 1001 unable to get installer types in the C:\Program Files(x86)\Default Company Name\Setup\Project.exe

Tags: c#, custom-action

I got this exception while installing my application on client's laptop. I have used custom action for this setup. this exception occurs before calling function

```
protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
```

[image: Exception While installation]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581750/error-with-windows-installer-unable-to-get-installer-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need to add dependent DLLs to the setup project. I had used 3rd party toolkit dll in my project and i had added it to the reference but here I need to add it in setup as well(make folder ThirdPartyDLL and add all 3rd party DLL in this folder). also have installed crystal report on target machine because my project is using crystal report.

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer a little?  You say you added MyDLL as a reference, but that you "need to add it also in solution". What do you mean "I need to add it also in solution"?   That you needed to add the `MyDLL.dll` **file** to the project using Add New -> Add Existing Item?

Comment: @Tim I mean you need to add dlls to setup project, so that installer will copy all dependency dlls to destination machine

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you are calling that executable as a custom action and you have erroneously marked it as an installer class when it's really just a Win32 executable.

Comment: when i install it on my computer then it is installed without showing me any error. But it gives exception on clients computer...why so?

Comment: and one more thing is chatarpatarPro.exe is my config file in which i am saving my dynamic connection string

Comment: You haven't responded to my comment about whether it's Win32 or .NET, so my psychic powers are failing. It could be dependencies like C++ runtime. NET framework. Basically you need to answer my question about if it's a .NET program or a Win32 program before getting any further.

Comment: its .net program...now that problem is solved..I just installed crystal report on client's machine as it is dependency and added dll to the solution which are listed in dependency